# como puedo devolver un valor diferente de acuedo a los resultado de una consulta?

Tags: mysql

Tengo una consulta que en la parte de sexo me lo tira en booleano, pero quiero que cuando devuelva  0 se chica y cuando sea 1 sea chico.

```
SELECT 
            Persona.Id,
            Persona.Nombre1 AS 'Primer Nombre',
            Persona.Nombre2 AS 'Segundo Nombre',
            Persona.Apellido1 AS 'Primer Apellido',
            Persona.Apellido2 AS 'Segundo Apellido',
            Persona.Sexo,
            Persona.Fecha_nacimiento AS 'Fecha Nacimiento',
            Persona.Tipo_Doc_Identificacion AS 'Docuemnto Identificacion',
            Persona.Numero_Documento as 'Numero Documento',
            Persona.Empresa,
            Persona.Cargo,
            Ocupacion.Nombre as Ocupacion,
            Provincia.Nombre as Provincia,
            Municipio.Nombre as Municipio,
            Barrio.Nombre as Barrio,
            Persona.Numero_casa As 'Numero Casa',
            Persona.Telefono_trabajo AS 'Telefono Trabajo',
            Persona.Telefono_casa AS 'Telefono Casa',
            Persona.Telefono_personal AS 'Telefono Personal',
            Persona.Email

        FROM
            Persona
            left join
            Ocupacion ON persona.Ocupacion = Ocupacion.Id
            left join
            Provincia ON persona.Provincia = Provincia.Id
            left join
            Municipio ON persona.Municipio = Municipio.Id
            left join 
            Barrio ON persona.Barrio = Barrio.Id where Eliminado = 0;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola prueba con este query:

```
SELECT 
            Persona.Id,
            Persona.Nombre1 AS 'Primer Nombre',
            Persona.Nombre2 AS 'Segundo Nombre',
            Persona.Apellido1 AS 'Primer Apellido',
            Persona.Apellido2 AS 'Segundo Apellido',
            if(Persona.Sexo=0,'F','M') AS 'Genero',
            Persona.Fecha_nacimiento AS 'Fecha Nacimiento',
            Persona.Tipo_Doc_Identificacion AS 'Docuemnto Identificacion',
            Persona.Numero_Documento as 'Numero Documento',
            Persona.Empresa,
            Persona.Cargo,
            Ocupacion.Nombre as Ocupacion,
            Provincia.Nombre as Provincia,
            Municipio.Nombre as Municipio,
            Barrio.Nombre as Barrio,
            Persona.Numero_casa As 'Numero Casa',
            Persona.Telefono_trabajo AS 'Telefono Trabajo',
            Persona.Telefono_casa AS 'Telefono Casa',
            Persona.Telefono_personal AS 'Telefono Personal',
            Persona.Email

FROM
            Persona
            left join
            Ocupacion ON persona.Ocupacion = Ocupacion.Id
            left join
            Provincia ON persona.Provincia = Provincia.Id
            left join
            Municipio ON persona.Municipio = Municipio.Id
            left join 
            Barrio ON persona.Barrio = Barrio.Id where Eliminado = 0;
```

Answer (score 3):

Solo tenes que agregar a tu consulta, una condicion sobre ese campo para que devuelva otro valor.

Para eso podemos usar if, que en este caso, como es un campo que puede tomar solo dos valores nos alcanza.

Cambia dentro de tu select la linea que dice:

```
Persona.Sexo
```

por

```
if(Persona.Sexo=0,'femenino','masculino') as sexo
```